# Change column type VARCHAR to TEXT in PostgreSQL without lock table

Tags: postgresql, alter-table

I have a "Parent Table" and partition table by year with a lot column and now I need change a column `VARCHAR(32)` to `TEXT` because we need more length flexibility.

So I will alter the parent them will also change all partition.

But the table have 2 unique index with this column and also 1 index.

This query lock the table:

```
ALTER TABLE my_schema.my_table
ALTER COLUMN column_need_change TYPE VARCHAR(64) USING 
column_need_change :: VARCHAR(64);
```

Also this one :

```
ALTER TABLE my_schema.my_table
ALTER COLUMN column_need_change TYPE TEXT USING column_need_change :: TEXT;
```

I see this solution :

```
UPDATE pg_attribute SET atttypmod = 64+4
WHERE attrelid = 'my_schema.my_table'::regclass
AND attname = 'column_need_change ';
```

But I dislike this solution.

How can change `VARCHAR(32)` type to `TEXT` without lock table, I need continue to push some data in table between the update.

My Postgresql version : 9.6

EDIT :

This is the solution I ended up taking:

```
ALTER TABLE my_schema.my_table
ALTER COLUMN column_need_change TYPE TEXT USING column_need_change :: TEXT;
```

The query lock my table between : 1m 52s 548ms for 2.6 millions rows but it's fine.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The supported and safe variant is to use `ALTER TABLE`. This will *not* rewrite the table, since `varchar` and `text` have the same on-disk representation, so it will be done in a split second once the `ACCESS EXCLUSIVE` table lock is obtained.

Provided that your transactions are short, you will only experience a short stall while `ALTER TABLE` waits for all prior transactions to finish.

Messing with the system catalogs is dangerous, and you do so on your own risk.

You *might* get away with

```
UPDATE pg_attribute
SET atttypmod = -1,
    atttypid  = 25
WHERE attrelid = 'my_schema.my_table'::regclass
  AND attname = 'column_need_change';
```

But if it breaks something, you get to keep the pieces…

Comment: What might be non-obvious to some readers is that in Postgres (somebody please correct me if I'm wrong!) the length limit on a varchar field is effectively just a constraint on allowed values, and doesn't affect how the column is stored on disk. In most other DBMSes, increasing that length *would* require a table rewrite, because the row would be laid out on disk with only enough room for the originally specified limit.

Comment: You are right as far as PostgreSQL is concerned (I don't know about other DBMS).

Comment: @IMSoP: Oracle and SQL Server won't rewrite the table (or any index) either if the change is "compatible" e.g. from `varchar(20)` to `varchar(500)`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Ah, fair enough. I thought I remembered reading that SQL Server allocates a fixed width for each row based on the types and precisions specified, and assumed that meant rows would need to be rewritten with the new layout, particularly if allocating *extra* space. Certainly `varchar(max)` is not encouraged as a default in the way that `text` is in Postgres.

Comment: @IMSoP: that "fixed width" is used when estimating the memory needed for a query result, not for _storing_ the data on disk. See e.g. here: https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/162117/1822

Comment: Thank @LaurenzAlbe I will use the ALTER TABLE solution it lock my table between 2 minutes but it's fine.

Comment: The [Postgres docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-altertable.html#id-1.9.3.35.7) indicate that while the ALTER TABLE version will not rewrite the table for these types (the column contents isn't changing and the types are binary coercible), it will rewrite any indexes using the column regardless, which will lock the table for a time. If this is a big table, then the indexes might also be large, and so rewriting them might take considerable time. I hit this case. Just leaving a note for other intrepid readers.